# Update/delete queries cannot be typed at

Tags: java, sql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to execute this query:

```
        @Override
        public int deleteOldLogByDate(LocalDateTime created_at) throws Exception {

            String hql = "delete from " + Log.class.getName() + " e where e.created_at <= :created_at";
            TypedQuery<Log> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, Log.class).setParameter("created_at", created_at);
            int records = query.executeUpdate();
            return records;
        }
```

But I get exception:  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Update/delete queries cannot be typed at`

Do you know how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Bulk queries like update and delete cannot be used in TypedQuery (as the error says).

You have to use:

```
    @Override
    public int deleteOldLogByDate(LocalDateTime created_at) throws Exception {

        String hql = "delete from " + Log.class.getName() + " e where e.created_at <= :created_at";
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(hql).setParameter("created_at", created_at);
        int records = query.executeUpdate();
        return records;
    }
```